# bat file programmatically press enter to go next line

Tags: batch-file, jpm

When I run following command on cmd it ask me to press enter to continue. when I press enter it show the next thing and so on.we do this when  develop/create a new firefox addon using jpm tool.first it show default title if I hit enter it show default name and etc...

command `jpm init`

here is an snapshot

[image]

now I want to make a bat file for this. so it should go to next line like when I press enter .

I tried this. but it doesn't go to next line it show title..and wait..

`create.bat`

```
call jpm init
echo 
echo 
echo 
echo 
echo 
echo 
pause
```

How can I make a bat file for this?

Comment: Usually command line tools have parameters which you can specify to avoid entering them by hand interactively. Check the documentation of that jpm tool.

Comment: @wOxxOm here is the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#jpm_init . it doesn't show a way to avoid entering data by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(
echo/
echo/
echo/
echo/
echo/
echo/
) | call jpm init
pause
```

Comment: Or `(echo.&echo.&echo.&echo.&echo y) | call jpm init`

Comment: @Aacini thanks but there is a small problem.normally i have to hit enter 8 times but when i use above pipe method it requred only 4 echo lines .the problem echo print after skipping one line don't know why

Answer (score 1):

another method, that may (or may not) work for you:

```
<nul call jpm init
```

Whenever an input is required, it is taken from the NUL device.

Pro: no need to know how many inputs are required
Con: *every* input request is answered with RETURN